# How to update my DSDT (part of fix for no Ethernet card fix)

Tags: network, macos, mac-appstore

I have a MacBook w/ OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5) that had the original Wi-Fi card removed.  This happened before I got the computer and I cannot get it back.  Because of this, I'm using a USB Wi-Fi to connect to the internet.  The problem is when I try to connect to the App Store, I get the message

> Your device or computer could not be verified. Contact support for assistance.

I've done a lot of research and it seems this happens because Apple is trying to identify me based on the MAC address of my original Wi-Fi card and can't (see this [post](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/295534-mac-app-store-access-with-nullethernetkext/) and this [post](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-air-removed-airport-card-problems.1723989/#post-18975285)).  The only option in this case seems to be using a "fake" Ethernet card provided by [RehabMan](https://github.com/RehabMan/OS-X-Null-Ethernet).  I followed the instructions on his site, but I'm stuck at the point of patching my DSDT.

1. I added the NullEhternet.kext using by following an [osxdaily tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/12/how-to-manually-install-kernel-extensions-in-mac-os-x/)
2. I downloaded MaciASL from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/maciasl/)
3. I used MaciASL to open my DSDT and apply the patch.txt file
4. I compiled and got no errors, then saved the file as DSDT.asl to my desktop
5. I mounted my EFI partition with a [themacadmin](https://themacadmin.com/2012/02/15/mounting-the-efi-boot-partition-on-mac-os-x/) tutorial
6. **The last step says I should copy the .asl to my EFI partition**, but I don't have any of the folders the tutorial mentions!

What am I doing wrong?  Should I abandon this and try a different approach?

Comment: Have you contacted Support for assistance?

Comment: @Allan No.  I got the computer second hand *and* it was modified from it's original condition so I assumed I don't qualify for their support terms.

Comment: That's not how it works.  First, second, or third hand, you can contact support for issues with AppleID and your account.  You may just have to get a new WiFi card or use Ethernet to connect.

Comment: @Allan Thanks, I emailed them.  I'm outside the US and don't know if I'll be able to obtain an original part where I live, so if there's an option to make this workaround (or another one) work, I might need it!

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer is a little bit late coming but since I stumbled upon this post I'm sure others may in the future and if they are having any similar issues with Apple products and/or firmwares then here is the fix.

Download "[Open Core Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/)". It will fix that and about anything else and if you have a MacBook/iMac and you want to run the latest macOS on your MacBook or iMac etc.. Then that's what the tool is primarily been made for and it works flawlessly.

So maybe this may help someone who doesn't want to go spend 3000 dollars on a different MacBook or iMac in order to run the newest "RAM HOG", CPUThrottler, ResourceConsumer macOS New "Monterey", Ventura, etc.. Because truthfully there's not much difference between the two there and BigSur 11.7.2. Hell, even Catalina is still usable, along with Mojave. I hope this helps someone!